# One table, GROUP_CONCAT and multiple AND with FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve items which have all values I want.

The table:

```
+------+------+
| item |  val |
+------+------+
|   1  |  x   |
|   1  |  y   |
|   2  |  a   |
|   2  |  b   |
|   3  |  a   |
|   3  |  x   |
|   3  |  y   |
+------+------+
```

For example, I want the items which have x and y vals (items 1 and 3)

My SQL query:

```
SELECT item, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT val) AS vals
FROM test
GROUP BY item 
HAVING
    FIND_IN_SET('x', vals) AND
    FIND_IN_SET('y', vals)
```

That works, but I think that there is a better solution which doesn't use FIND_IN_SET function.

Comment: `SELECT item FROM vals WHERE val IN ('x', 'y') GROUP BY item HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT val) = 2` ? (replace 2 with the amount of searched values)

Comment: Of course, if distinct is actually required in this solution then you probably have bigger problems with your schema

Comment: Thanks @AlmaDo, it works!